# Please add a way to reach the question's site from the question

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Often (via Google Now, or when searching for a solution to some problem), I'll open a question from a non-favourite site in the app. Sometimes, I'd like to see what else is going on in the site where the question was posted. Currently, I have one of two ways:

1. Via tag icon:

   1. Click one of the tag icons beneath the title
   2. Delete the `[tag]` text (at which point, thankfully, the sorting changes to `Active` from `Votes`).
2. Via manually searching for the site, which is more cumbersome. I type in `hard` and *Hardware Recommendations* is the fourth entry (below *Ask Different*, *Raspberry Pi* and *Arduino*)! This more annoying for meta sites, where I have to pick `Meta` from the dropdown menu.

Can I pretty please have a way to head to the site directly from the question? Maybe:

- the site name in the top bar could become clickable and lead to the site, or
- an option in the `More` menu?

---

This would be especially useful for Meta sites, where questions posted around the same time could be related. Interestingly enough, most questions that Google Now are for metas of sites I visit on occasion, but haven't pinned to the list.

Comment: I think the site name in the top bar should be made clickable.

Comment: @nicael Nice idea! Adding it to the post.